# How to convert these text segments to CSV?

Tags: csv, text, anki

I'm trying to make a CSV file out of a text file with html tags with questions and answers.
Unfortunately, I've tried and wasn't able to open it in LibreOffice or any other CSV compatible software.
What I'm trying to do is to convert something like this:

```
<b>Question 1:</b> What is the capital of United States?
<b>Answer:</b> Washington, D.C.

<b>Question 2:</b> What is the capital of United States?
<b>Answer:</b> Washington, D.C.

<b>Question 3:</b> What is the capital of United States?
<b>Answer:</b> Washington, D.C.
```

And so on.

The result should be:

```
Question SEPARATOR Answer
```

*SEPARATOR cannot be a color or semicolon because the question might contain most important characters (colon, semicolon, dots)

I want to import into Anki and it supports CSV files.

I've tried separating Question and Answer with a special symbol like # and only the questions are parsed in LibreOffice/OpenOffice and the question text can never contain a line break. If a text contains a line break, the CSV gets messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little Python script to convert your cards to CSV format:

```
import re
import csv

questions = [[]]

with open("original.file", "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            questions[-1].append(line)
        else:
            questions.append([])

# Now we've got the questions in a 2D list.
# Let's just make sure it loaded properly.
assert all(len(question) == 2 for question in questions)

# Let's write a CSV file now.
with open("output.csv", "wt", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for q, a in questions:
        writer.writerow([
            re.fullmatch(r"<b>Question \d+:</b> (.*)", q).group(1),
            re.fullmatch(r"<b>Answer:</b> (.*)", a).group(1)
        ])
```

Now you can import these with the "Basic" card type. This code discards the question number; I hope that wasn't too important.